# How to split Table header into 2 lines

Tags: tables

I have a table with a long header text

[image]

I tried to split the header into 2 rows but I got an error in the Tex when I added \

Here is my tex

```
\begin{table*}[htbp]
    \caption{AutoML platforms used in the healthcare research}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            \textbf{\textit{Research}} & \textbf{{Commercial AutoML (Google AutoML and Apple Create ML)}}&  \textbf{\textit{T1}}& \textbf{\textit{T2}}& \textbf{\textit{T3}}
            & \textbf{\textit{T4}}& \textbf{\textit{T5}}
            & \textbf{\textit{T6}}\\
            \hline
            [36]&.&.&.&.&.&.&X\\
            \hline          
            [37]&.&.&.&.&.&.&X\\
            \hline

            
        \end{tabular}
        \label{graph_i}
    \end{center}
\end{table*}
```

Is there a way to break the header into to 2 lines?

Thanks

Comment: please use the package `makecell` and edit the code as under -- for  `            \textbf{\textit{Research}} & \textbf{{Commercial AutoML (Google AutoML and Apple Create ML)}}&  \textbf{\textit{T1}}& \textbf{\textit{T2}}& \textbf{\textit{T3}}
` add ----  `\textbf{\textit{Research}} & \textbf{\thead{Commercial AutoML \\(Google AutoML and Apple Create ML)}}&  \textbf{\textit{T1}}& \textbf{\textit{T2}}& \textbf{\textit{T3}}`

Comment: You can also use `\nulticolumn{1}{p{1in}}{...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   \textbf{\textit{Research}} & \textbf{\thead{Commercial AutoML \\(Google AutoML and Apple Create ML)}}&  \textbf{\textit{T1}}& \textbf{\textit{T2}}& \textbf{\textit{T3}}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \textbf{\textit{Research}} & \textbf{\thead{Commercial AutoML \\(Google AutoML and Apple Create ML)}}&  \textbf{\textit{T1}}& \textbf{\textit{T2}}& \textbf{\textit{T3}}
    & \textbf{\textit{T4}}& \textbf{\textit{T5}}
    & \textbf{\textit{T6}}\\
    \hline
    [36]&.&.&.&.&.&.&X\\
    \hline          
    [37]&.&.&.&.&.&.&X\\
    \hline
    
    
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Undefined control sequence. ...ML\\(Google AutoML and Apple Create ML)}}

Comment: use package makecell in preamble